# MySQL Speeding Up Restoration of dump file in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

We have around 20 GB of backup data. we took backup using by below command in MySQL 5.5 Server.

```
mysqldump -u username -p password (database Name) > Backupfile.sql
```

Now we are trying to restore same data in MySQL 5.7 Server. after immediate installation of MySQL 5.7.

It's taking huge time to restore the data.

We did search in google, we found this.

https://serverfault.com/questions/146525/how-can-i-speed-up-a-mysql-restore-from-a-dump-file

But its not helping.

Is there any other way to speed up this restoration process.

Thanks...

Comment: Restoring a 20 GB file takes time.

Comment: @Aashick - if there a more Databases (Schemas ) in the dump file, then you can split the dump into pieces (via awk or sed) and import them by starting the import for each file.

Comment: No, we are taking single Database backup